# Telerik Kendo UI Scaffolding failed on ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6 + EF7 RC1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error in my current ASP.NET 5 project when I try to scaffold a Grid. I never had this error on MVC 5. Is this because of Telerik not supporting MVC 6 or there is another reason?

### Model

[Click here](http://pastie.org/private/mm13tlf3go9ngoakvttmoq)

### ViewModel

[Click here](http://pastie.org/private/xfurswhlmi3kbxnkjiqkw)

### ApplicationDbContext

[Click here](http://pastie.org/private/cwjwbvxxfrmunn3y5dfda)

[image]

Comment: How do you expect people to help you without seeing any code? Kendo (Telerik is the name of the company, not the product) supports asp.net MVC 6. 

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-6/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Kendo UI Scaffolder does not support MVC 6 environment.

[image: Telerik Response]